# Is there a 'Messenger of the Gods' figure in Egyptian mythology?

Tags: egyptian

While Thoth is often equated with Hermes, he seems to be more of a keeper of secret wisdom than a messenger.

Is there any such figure in Egyptian mythology?

Comment: Great question.  Welcome to Mythology!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other than the little known Apt, arguably the closest direct Egyptian analog to Hermes would be the synthetic deity [Hermanubis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermanubis). Who is, as you might guess from the name, the result of combining of Anubis and Hermes. He only emerged in [Ptolemaic Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemaic_Kingdom) however, so a little on the late side of ancient mythologies.

The combination was rooted in the role of Anubis as the conductor of souls, a trait he shares with Hermes. However Anubis was also the messenger of Osiris in the Book of the Dead, and, according to [E. A. Wallis Budge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._A._Wallis_Budge), the "chief envoy of Ra". The ancient writer [Apuleius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apuleius) likewise calls Anubis the messenger of gods, although that's probably the Roman projecting attributes from Mercury or Hermes.

- Budge, A. E. W. *The Papyrus of Ani: The Theban Recension of the Book of the Dead.* The Medici Society, London 1913.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said: "The combination was rooted in the role of Anubis as the conductor of souls, a trait he shares with Hermes"